# как заблокировать комбинацию клавиш alt + F4

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

я пытался найти в интернете как заблокировать комбинацию клавиш alt + F4 но ничего не нашел кроме одной статьи в которой говорилось вписать

```
root.bind(<"alt + f4">, somefunction)
```

но ето не сработало

мне надо чтоб мое окно tkitner не закрывали

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашел другой способ, если у кого возник такой же вопрос, вот код:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

и
import keyboard

```
keyboard.add_hotkey("alt + f4", lambda: None, suppress =True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
def on_closing():
    ms.showerror('Error', 'Невозможно выйти!')
tk.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

Такое окно возможно закрыть только через диспетчер задач.

Comment: Ну, да. Или пкиллом.